# Listing answers for question(get_object_or_404) in for loop. How can I get each answer also as an object in one def?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I am sorry if my title doesn't make much sense for you. I have a problem and I have a problem with describing it. I will be very grateful if you could help me.

I have small voting system for my question objects. My questions have many answers that I am listing in "question_details" in for loop. I can of course access question model and therefore get informations about votes for question but I am unable to do the same for each answer. Maybe some code to better illustrate:

views.py:

```
def questiondetails(request, question_pk):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_pk)
    question_form_id = question
    total_voteup = question.total_voteup()
    total_votedown = question.total_votedown()
    is_voteup = False
    is_votedown = False
       if question.voteup.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
           is_voteup = True
       if question.votedown.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
           is_votedown = True
```

I can check about of votes, and I can check if user vote up or down.

in templates of questiondetails I am doing something like that:

```
{% for answer in question.answer_set.all %}
    {{ answer }}<br>
    <div id="answer_voting_section">
    {% include 'main/partials/answer_voting_section.html' %}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And with that. I can click on my question, it will trigger "questiondetails" and bring me to it's page with question and answers coming from this for loop.

And my problem is, that I would like to access "total_voteup" (and other stuff) for each answer from that for loop.

How can I do it ? I am new at python at django so I only understand that I am able to do it with question and question details because I am PASSING a "question_pk". Can I in the same DEF also access answers associated with this question ? Or it is impossible because this data is "not yet visible" for django ?

@Edit:

My models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    answered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    datecompleted = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    voteup = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='voteup', blank=True)
    votedown = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='votedown', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def total_voteup(self):
        return self.voteup.count()

    def total_votedown(self):
        return self.votedown.count()


class Answer(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)
    answer = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_voteup = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='answer_voteup', blank=True)
    answer_votedown = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='answer_votedown', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

    def total_answer_voteup(self):
        return self.answer_voteup.count()

    def total_answer_votedown(self):
        return self.answer_votedown.count()
```

Comment: Can you share your models? Can one vote on a question, or on an answer?

Comment: I added my models id edit. Each user can vote on everything, question and each answer. One question can have many answers. Each vote can be UP or DOWN, and if user already voted UP he can revert it by clicking one more time.

Comment: Do you want to calculate total answer from a particular user, I don't really get you question. Or total answer to a single questions.? <br> if for a particular question you can use the object set _set, or for a user you can edit the instance.

Comment: I am not sure that are you exactly asking about. I have votes + and - to both question and answers. Each of them have "total_vote" value, it means + and = combined on this question/answer. Each user can vote + or - for each question and each answer.

I can acces all of it for question (since I am passing question_pk). But I am missing some values for answers (like total votes up and down) because I cannot create "answer" object in my questiondetails def. Or can I ?

Comment: Ok i understand now i understand i think i can help you, give me few minutes. But the answers total vote up and down must be related to that particular questions??

Comment: Of course, thank you very much for your time. I will be waiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there's lots of redundancy on your code and your answer model doesn't need to use question_id field django will create id for you, the answer field is suppose to rather have the models.OneToMany relationship.
 but you can import answer model to the view and do something similar as you did for the questioniare upvote and downvote inside same view i.e
  answer_upvote = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=question).total_answer_voteup()
answer_downvote = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=question).total_answer_votedown()

The logic i am trying to use is getting all object related to each questions

but this way you can work around.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I encountered problem. I got "'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'total_answer_voteup'". I imported answer model into my views.py. And I wrote - "total_answer_voteup = Answer.objects.filter(answer=question).total_answer_voteup()" And it gave me this query error. Is it because this question query don't have this answer attributes ?

Comment: It seems the method you created  could not be assessed why not query the fields directly. <br> answer_upvote = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=question).values('answer_vote_up').count()  answer_downvote = Answer.objects.filter(question_id=question).values('answer_vote_down').count(). <br /> Note: you can as well substitute values() with values_list() to query more than one fields. Hope this is solved now.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help. I rebuilt big part of my code related to voting on answers but I still used your advices. Thank you :)